# Replace "names" of columns of a data frame with different (new) names in another file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I have two data frames: One (dataframe A) is like as follows:

```
S.No    A1     A2    A3   A4     A6
  1      0      0     0    0      0
  2      2      4     7    7      9
  3      6      7     9    10     0
```

and so on.

Another (dataframe B) file is like as follows:

```
S.No   old_names      new_names
   1     A1              qq
   2     A2              ww
   3     A3              gg
   4     A4              zz
   5     A6              mm
```

**Names of A need not be in same sequence as of B$old_names.**

My new file should look like:

```
S.No    qq     ww    gg   zz     mm
  1      0      0     0    0      0
  2      2      4     7    7      9
  3      6      7     9    10     0
```

IS there any simpler way to do this in R without using for loop and comparing both files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Both files are too big.

Comment: `names(dataframe1) <- dataframe2$new_names`?

Comment: @Hugh Thank you. Problem with this is that names of dataframe1 need not be in the same sequence as dataframe2. This will fail in that case.

Answer (score 4):

```
n <- names(df1)[-1]  # get rid of S.No

names(df1) <- c("S.No", as.character(df2$new_names)[match(n, df2$old_names)])
```