# how to append names to " column names" of the output data frame in R?

Tags: r

i know that i can change the names of columns using

```
colnames(x)<-c("Column1" , "Column 2" ,"Column 3", "Column 4")
```

If I have

```
A<-"Apple"  
B<-"Banana"
```

What should I do so that the names of the output data frame will have names like this

```
"Column 1 Apple" "Column 2 Banana" "Column 3 Apple" "Column 4 Banana"
```

I have looked at 
[Replace "names" of columns of a data frame with different (new) names in another file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359937/replace-names-of-columns-of-a-data-frame-with-different-new-names-in-another)
and
[How to dynamically assign names to dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676983/how-to-dynamically-assign-names-to-dataframes)
But I didn't quite understand how to apply it to my case.

Comment: You should stay away from having spaces in your column names, imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `paste` and rely on the fact that R recycles vectors. As @Richard noted, you should avoid spaces in column/variable names to make your life easier. `make.names` can take care of that:

```
make.names(paste(names(x), c(A,B)))
#[1] "Column1.Apple"  "Column2.Banana" "Column3.Apple"  "Column4.Banana"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I just wanted to know , how to apply the above solution selectively to columns of my choice?   

for instance if I wanted to arrive at an output like this     
`"Column1.Apple" "Column2" "Column3" "Column4.Banana"  `

Comment: @kRazzyR - subset your columns as appropriate. `colnames(x)[c(1,4)] <- make.names(paste(names(x)[c(1,4)], c(A,B) ))`