# Can dataframe's name in R can use as Stata local function?

Tags: r, stata

In Stata, variable name can us local function define.

such as `local var="longtime"`

```
`var'_2010`
```

is actually `longtime_2010` in Stata

Can R have the same function as local in dataframe.

I have repeat my code in the same step in several dataframes.

But I have to change their names. How can I use the same as Stata.
such as

I have var1-10

var1<-left_join(var1_tot,var1_exp)

.....(repeat 10 times)

var10<-left_join(var10_tot,var10_exp)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you elaborate and clarify your question?

Comment: Locals is not a general concept, it is just what Stata calls non-dataset/datafram variables with a short scope. I think your question is "Can column names in a dataframe be assigned dynamically?". If so, does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489395/how-to-append-names-to-column-names-of-the-output-data-frame-in-r

Comment: in Stata a local macro (not function) is a container for a text string, which could be the name of a variable -- or several such names. Again, a variable in Stata is in other terms a column in a dataset.

Comment: @NickCox Can I container for a text string, to name my data frame in R as stata?

Comment: It is technically possible in R using `assign` and `get`, but R has better alternatives: [Use a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you have associated objects they are put into a list and then one can iterate over the lists.  Questions on SO are supposed to have complete reproducible input.  Please read the info at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page regarding asking questions.

In the absence of that we will provide L1 and L2 below based on the built in BOD data frame.  Each of these is a list of 3 data frames but could have been 10 data frames.

```
library(dplyr)

L1 <- list(BOD, 2*BOD, 3*BOD)
L2 <- list(2*cbind(BOD[1], x = 1:6), 3*cbind(BOD[1], x = 1:6), 4*cbind(BOD[1], x = 1:6))

L3 <- Map(left_join, L1, L2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 10 data frames `var1_tot`, `var2_tot`, ... `var10_tot`, and another 10 data frames `var1_exp`, `var2_exp`, ... `var10_exp`, and you want to left join each of these pairwise.  You can do this, using `get` within `lapply()` as follows.  This will return a list of 10 dataframes, the first being `var1_tot` left-joined with `var1_exp`, the second being `var2_tot` left-joined with `var2_exp`, etc.

```
lapply(1:10, \(v) {
  dfs = paste0("var",v,c("_tot", "_exp"))
  dplyr::left_join(get(dfs[1]), get(dfs[2]))
})
```